# What are the common methodology can be used to find the parameter of the fixed and random effect in a nonlinear mixed effect model?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, longitudinal-data-analysis

Recently, I am doing some research about nonlinear mixed effect model. However, most of the time, they will just straight away use the R language nlme package and fit the model into it to get the result. Therefore, I am wonder what is the algorithm or methodology behind it..... I couldn't find any book or journal article which specifically explain the method to solve a nonlinear mixed effect model. Any recommended book or study material for solving nlme?

Answer (score 2):

This paper has a lot of the details you're probably after (section 3 in particular):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf

Although it's for lme4 rather than nlme. I'm not sure what the differences are under the hood.